# How I can get Unix files using ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, unix

Team, I started working with Microsoft .NET 3.5. then I have to obtain and show two Unix files in my project. please do you have any how do it?

Answer (score 1):

UNIX files are just text files, so this should be no problem. However, you may have to set up a [Samba](http://us1.samba.org/samba/) drive if you need to grab them from a Unix server.